# Using Fastlane in a TFS build randomly hangs

Tags: tfs, fastlane

I'm using Fastlane from a Mac Mini to re-sign a mobile application via a TFS build.
Everything worked pretty well until builds started hanging after Fastlane declared the job completed successfully.

The logs from the agent look like this

```
[2018-07-10 09:44:49Z INFO ProcessInvoker] Process started with process id 33245, waiting for process exit. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:49Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:49Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:50Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to upload 1 log files or attachments, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:55Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:56Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:56Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:58Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:44:59Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:01Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:16Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:17Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:22Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:22Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:22Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:23Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:24Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:39Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:41Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:41Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:42Z INFO JobServerQueue] Try to append 1 batches web console lines, success rate: 1/1. 
[2018-07-10 09:45:57Z INFO JobServerQueue] Stop aggressive process web console line queue.
```

Everytime this line appears :

```
Stop aggressive process web console line queue.
```

The job hangs and the build fails after the 60 minutes time limit set.

The status of the fastlane step doesnt seem to be important in this case since most of the time Fastlane outputs through TFS :

```
2018-07-23T07:00:09.4879740Z 
2018-07-23T07:00:09.4890680Z [09:00:09]: [32mfastlane.tools just saved you 14 minutes! [0m
2018-07-23T07:16:16.5905860Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2018-07-23T07:16:16.5987280Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Fastlane
```

If anyone has an idea, I'm all ears.

We've tried restarting the Fastlane machine, perform a gem cleanup apart from that aggressive console alert, nothing seems out of order.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say TFS build randomly hangs, did you just mean you have ever build successfully and could not reproduce the issue reliably?

Comment: Exactly, sometimes the Fastlane actions will complete and the job will stop which would take less than two minutes. 
Other times, when the line appears, the job times out after 60 minutes with no log from the Fastlane job other than success.